# SQL - how to add column with average value, grouped

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, average

Essentially, what I'm starting with is this in TABLE_A

```
France - 100

France - 200

France - 300

Mexico - 50

Mexico - 50

Mexico - 56

Poland - 100

Poland - 150
```

And What I want to have at the end is an added column, with the value average by country.

```
France - 100 - 200

France - 200 - 200

France - 300 - 200

Mexico - 500 - 520

Mexico - 500 - 520

Mexico - 560 - 520

Poland - 100 - 125

Poland - 150 - 125
```

I'd like to do this by updating/altering TABLE_A and not creating a new table if possible.  I'm working in Oracle. Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Is the plan to have a trigger that updates the averages ever time a row is inserted or updated? Why add a column to the table which is the result on an aggregation?

Comment: The table will not be updated - I need to add this column to the current table so it's present when I export to another program.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `avg() over()`. I don't see a reason for storing these computed columns. They would have to be updated each time a new row is added or when rows in the table get updated.

```
select t.*, avg(val) over(partition by country) average
from yourtable t
```

To add it as a column, do:

```
alter yourtable add average number(10,2);

commit;

update yourtable t
set t.average = (select avg(val) 
                 from yourtable 
                 where country = t.country)
;

commit;
```

Comment: This table doesn't get updated, so that's not a concern.  I have to export this table to another program, so the column has to be added now so this computed column can be used in the other program.

Is there a way to add this column to TABLE_A that you know of?

Comment: Ah, ok. So it's very different problem than what I was thinking. Again, don't break the normalization for this, as this is sure to bite you when you find out a typo months later and need to export the data again.

Comment: @jdjohnson920: Why can't you simply add the calculation during the export, either directly or using a view?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: don't do that. You're breaking the database normalization, for something that can be done with functions. As you are doing this in Oracle, you can write a function with RESULT CACHE clause, something like

```
FUNCTION average_by_country (country_id IN countries.id%TYPE)
RETURN countries.whatever%TYPE
RESULT_CACHE RELIES_ON (countries)
IS
```

etc etc, this will cache the result for each country, making the function evaluation very fast.

Then, you can select this average with

```
SELECT country_id, country_name, country_data, average_by_country(country_id)
FROM countries WHERE etc etc
```

Comment: Of course, you can just use a "AVG(country_data)" with "GROUP BY" in the select, but I assumed that if you're not using that it's because you really need the extra performance. Anyway, you should compare the performance of using the cached function with the AVG & GROUP BY queries in your real data.

Comment: I appreciate the sentiment, but I need to add this column - this table is getting exported for use elsewhere, so it's not my call.  I just need to add the column, whether it breaks normalization or not.
----------------------

Do you know whether or not it's possible to add this column to TABLE_A?  I know how to AVG(variable) group by, but I don't need to select.  I need to write this into TABLE_A.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Add the column with a "ALTER TABLE" command, then update it with a subquery, something like "UPDATE countries SET new_column = (SELECT avg(bla bla))". I really can't provide a full working code as you didn't provide us with the table structure.

Comment: I've done the ALTER TABLE, and I have an update statement that looks like  UPDATE table_a SET new_column =(AVG(amount) GROUP BY countryname).  That is breaking though, as it says a group function doesn't work here.  The table structure is as simple as the OP makes it seem - one column with country names, second column with amounts, and that's it

Answer (score 0):

```
declare
cursor c_records is 
   select movie_id, count(*) cnt, avg(rating) avgr
   from   ratings 
   group  by movie_id;
l_i number := 0;   
begin
   for l_rec in c_records loop
      update movies
      set    avg_user_rating = l_rec.avgr,
             rating_count = l_rec.cnt
      where  movie_id = l_rec.movie_id;
      l_i := l_i + 1;
      if mod(l_i, 1000) = 0 then
         commit;
      end if;
   end loop;
end;
```

Took 9 seconds, whereas

```
update movies m
set    avg_user_rating = 
(
   select avg(r.rating)
   from   ratings r
   where  r.movie_id = m.movie_id
)
```

was cancelled after 9 hours, since it still did not complete.